# How old are the Martian blueberries?

Tags: mars, water, geology

The [martian blueberries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_spherules) (only blue in false color) found by the Opportunity rover in Meridium Planis are formed by slow evaporation in mineral-rich liquid water. They obviously formed early in the Martian history, but do we know more precisely when these blueberries formed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's call them "hematite spherules".

In principle, things on the Marsian surface can last a long time, billions of years https://sci.esa.int/web/mars-express/-/55481-the-ages-of-mars and https://science.sciencemag.org/content/343/6169/1247166.full state that a mudstone sample was deposited before 1.6Gy.

Unfortunately, the answer so far is *we do not know*. As longs the formation processes of the spherules aren't known, everything is open. If they formed in mid-air during a meteorite impact they may just be a few years old (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0032063314000245) (*). But if they formed in a similar process as those on earth they may be older than 3 billion years (https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/4/12/eaau0872.full).